# Set number of threads using omp_set_num_threads() to 2, but omp_get_num_threads() returns 1

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, openmp

I have the following C/C++ code using OpenMP:

```
    int nProcessors=omp_get_max_threads();
    if(argv[4]!=NULL){
        printf("argv[4]: %s\n",argv[4]);
        nProcessors=atoi(argv[4]);
        printf("nProcessors: %d\n",nProcessors);
    }
    omp_set_num_threads(nProcessors);
    printf("omp_get_num_threads(): %d\n",omp_get_num_threads());
    exit(0);
```

As you can see, I'm trying to set the number of processors to use based on an argument passed on the command line.

However, I'm getting the following output:

```
argv[4]: 2   //OK
nProcessors: 2   //OK
omp_get_num_threads(): 1   //WTF?!
```

Why isn't `omp_get_num_threads()` returning 2?!!!

---

As has been pointed out, I'm calling `omp_get_num_threads()` in a serial region, hence the function returns `1`.

However, I have the following parallel code:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,j,tid,_hash) firstprivate(firstTime) reduction(+:nChunksDetected)
    for(i=0;i<fileLen-CHUNKSIZE;i++){
        tid=omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("%d\n",tid);
        int nThreads=omp_get_num_threads();
        printf("%d\n",nThreads);
...
```

which outputs:

```
0   //tid
1   //nThreads - this should be 2!
0
1
0
1
0
1
...
```

Comment: Are you calling this from a serial portion of your program? If yes, the number of threads is actually 1.

Comment: He stephan - many thanks for that insight. I've edited the OP with another related question.

Comment: If you use Intel IPP libraries with OpenMP enabled, I've seen some cases in which they collide...

Comment: That's interesting. I'm using Intel thread building blocks...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `omp_get_num_threads()` call returns 1 in the serial section of the code. See [Link](http://www.serc.iisc.ernet.in/facilities/ComputingFacilities/systems/cluster/xlf/html/xlflr/lr407.htm)

So you need to have parallel code to get the correct value, here how your code should look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int nProcessors = omp_get_max_threads();

    std::cout<<nProcessors<<std::endl;

    omp_set_num_threads(nProcessors);

    std::cout<<omp_get_num_threads()<<std::endl;

#pragma omp parallel for 
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        std::cout<<tid<<"\t tid"<<std::endl;
        int nThreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        std::cout<<nThreads<<"\t nThreads"<<std::endl;
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

This code produces:

2

```
1
0    tid
2    nThreads
0    tid
2    nThreads
0    tid
2    nThreads
1    tid
2    nThreads
1    tid
2    nThreads
```

It seems that you have either open mp not enabled or your loop is not in the form that can be parallized by openmp

Comment: OK, but when I go into a parallel region, it's still returning 1... Please see my edit. Many thanks...

Comment: Where are you starting your parallel region, i do not see it in the edit.

Comment: Thanks, do you change the variable i or fileLen inside your parallel region? As it might be that your for loop cannot be parallised by openmp, due side effects.

Comment: No - don't change those variables

Comment: I have edited my code above and it works for me, please show some minimal running example where your code produces this error.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. It turns out that I needed to pass -fopenmp to LIBS and CXXFLAGS in my Makefile... ;(

Answer (score 13):

you are using the wrong function. use `omp_get_max_threads` to check for the maximum number of allowed threads.

Answer (score 3):

It has been already pointed out that `omp_get_num_threads()` returns `1` in sequential sections of the code. Accordingly, even if setting, by `omp_set_num_threads()`, an overall number of threads larger than `1`, any call to `omp_get_num_threads()` will return `1`, unless we are in a parallel section. The example below tries to clarify this point

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <omp.h>

int main() {

    const int maxNumThreads = omp_get_max_threads();

    printf("Maximum number of threads for this machine: %i\n", maxNumThreads);

    printf("Not yet started a parallel Section: the number of threads is %i\n", omp_get_num_threads());

    printf("Setting the maximum number of threads...\n");
    omp_set_num_threads(maxNumThreads);

    printf("Once again, not yet started a parallel Section: the number of threads is still %i\n", omp_get_num_threads());

    printf("Starting a parallel Section...\n");

#pragma omp parallel for 
    for (int i = 0; i < maxNumThreads; i++) {
        int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("This is thread %i announcing that the number of launched threads is %i\n", tid, omp_get_num_threads());
    }

}
```